# Show that h fulfill the linearity requirements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem, I am uncertain of how to solve:

[image]

Is it enough to show:

$L_1$: $g(f(v_1)+f(v_2)) =$ $g(fv_1)+g(fv_2)$

$L_2$: $k*g(f(v)) = $ $g(kf(v))$

And if so, should I find the mapping matrices for $ g$ and $f$ or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $f$ and $g$ are linear and so proving $gf$ is linear can be done without using their matrices.

$$gf(v_1+v_2)=g(f(v_1)+f(v_2))=g(f(v_1))+g(f(v_2))$$ 
$$gf(kv)=g(kf(v))=kg(f(v))$$

Note that $g(v_1)+g(v_3)=v_1$ and $g(v_1)-g(v_3)=2v_3$. You can use linearity to then find that  $g(v_1)=\frac{1}{2}v_1+v_3$ and $g(v_3)=\frac{1}{2}v_1-v_3$.

Now all you have to do is equate $gf(av_1+bv_2+cv_3)$ to $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and solve for $a,b,c$.

By linearity $f(av_1+bv_2+cv_3)=(4a-2b+2c,c,-2a+b-c)$.

Applying $g$ I now get

$$(a-b/2+c/2,c,6a-3b+3c)$$

To equal $(a,b,c)$ we need $6a=b=c$.

Comment: Yeah, I know I need to prove those two requirements, but my question was how I should do it? I mean, how can I justify that what you have written right there is true, when I have no formula for the functions?

Comment: The proof is complete. Look at the first equation - the first step uses linearity of $f$ which you are given. The next step uses linearity of $g$ which you are also given.

Comment: Hmm, I see thank you. What about the other part of the question, about finding two fixvectors for h? Aren't I going to need matrices for that part?

Comment: Its probably easier not to. I'll add something above.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say that g(v1)+g(v3)=v1. You don't have any numbers or coordinates for v1 or v3. Also, when you write gf(av1 + bv2 + cv3) do you mean g(f(av1 + bv2 + cv3))?

Comment: I have assumed that the notation (1,0,1) means $v_1+v_3$ since we've been told the $v_i$ are the basis.

Comment: Re the $gf$ query - yes, that is what $gf$ is defined to mean.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much, but I really don't quite get it. How am I supposed to find out what f(av1 + bv2 + bv3) is? We are mapping from V -> V, meanwhile f is only shown mapping from V -> R^3, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show this but I type very slowly!

Comment: That's totally fine sir take as long as you need to! I'm just so happy that you are this generous and willing to help a slow-minded like me :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm finally starting to understand the entire thing. One last thing though. I don't get how you are applying g. It seems like you are dividing the first part (4a-2b+2c) with 4, doing nothing to the middle part (c) and multiplying the last part (-2a+b-c) with -3. Can you explain how that happens?

Comment: Yes - that's right for the middle part since $g$ maps$v_2$ to itself. The others are more complicated though- remember $g(v_1)=\frac{1}{2}v_1+v_3$ and so you have to do that to $(4a-2b+2c)v_1$ but you then need to add the result of $g$ acting on the other two components - its long winded to explain!

Comment: You'll probably get more confidence if you first check my final answer. Can you find the result of applying $f$ and then $g$ to $v_1+6v_2+6v_3$. You should find you get  $v_1+6v_2+6v_3$ i.e. it is fixed.

Comment: I, unfortunately, need to say "no" to that question. I simply don't see what neither f nor g is doing to the vector $v_1 + 6v_2 +6v_3$ and I don't understand why the solution (a,b,c) needs to be 6a=b=c.

Comment: I'm adding another answer to try to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Are you happy that $f(v_1)=4v_1-2v_3$ and $f(v_2)=-2v_1+v_3$ and $f(v_3)=2v_1+v_2-1v_3$?

Good. So now consider $f(av_1+bv_2+cv_3$).
By linearity, this will be:-
$$a(4v_1-2v_3)+b(-2v_1+v_3)+c(2v_1+v_2-1v_3)$$

Good. So now you have got to line -4 of my previous answer.

$f(av_1+bv_2+cv_3)=(4a-2b+2c,c,-2a+b-c)$.

We now have to do this process again for $g$.
You should get $(a-b/2+c/2,c,6a-3b+3c)$

We now require $g(4a-2b+2c,c,-2a+b-c)$. Let's do $g(4a-2b+2c)v_1$ first. It is $$(2a-b+c)v_1+(4a-2b+2c)v_3$$

Now for $g(cv_2)$. Easy! It's just $cv_2$.

Finally you need to work out $g((-2a+b-c)v_3)$.

Now we must equate $$(a-b/2+c/2,c,6a-3b+3c)=(a,b,c)$$ since we are looking for a fixed vector.

For the first coefficient we have $a-b/2+c/2=a$ and therefore $b=c$. This also deals with the coefficients of $v_2$.

For the final coefficient we have $6a-3b+3c=c$ and this gives $c=6a$.

Comment: Yes, because (4,0,0)=4 $v_1$ and (0,0,-2)=-2 $v_3$. $(-2,0,0)=-2v_1$ and (0,0,1)=$1v_3$.

Comment: Yes, because $f(av_1 = af(v_1) = a(4v_1-2v_3)$. And so on.

Comment: $(4a-2b+2c)v_1 +(cv_2) + (-2a+1b-1c)v_3$.

Comment: You'll need to include the $a$s etc. So the first one should be $4a-2b+2c$.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my comment now, and I think it's correct.

Comment: I'm will try. $g(v_1)=1/2v_1+v_3 =(2a-b+c)+(-2a+b-c)=0$? That can't be right, am I supposed to add before I mupltiply?

Comment: I'll type it into the new answer.

Comment: $g((-2a+b-c)v_3) =(-a+b/2 -c/2)v_1-(-2a+b-c)v_3$

Comment: That's good but it's minus the last term

Comment: Now add our last three answers and it should come to the last but one line of my previous answer. Is that OK?

Comment: $((2a-b+c)+(-a+b/2-c/2)v_1) = a-b/2+c/2$.
$((4a-2b+2c)+(2a-b+c)v_3) = 6a-3b+3c$.
$v_2=c$

Comment: Yes - let's write it as $(a-b/2+c/2,c,6a-3b+3c)$.

Comment: Now this must equal $(a,b,c)$ if $( a,b,c)$ is to be a fixed vector.

Comment: Yes you've got the right idea. See the end of my second answer.

Comment: Ahhh, Okay I understand now. So any coefficients that make the equation $6a=b=c$ true is a fixvector. So for example, $v_1,6v_2,v_3$ and $2v_1,12v_2,12v_3$ are both fixvectors?

Comment: Yes but they must be added i.e. $v_1+6v_2+6v_3$ and $2v_1+12v_2+12v_3$ etc.

Comment: And if the basis is $a=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ then the vectors would be (1,6,6) and (2,12,12) with respect to the basis $a$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your patience, generosity and general professionalism in helping me. It means a lot. Have a good day sir, and take comfort in knowing you made a guy in need very happy :)

Comment: You can apply $gf$ to these vectors and see if they are really fixed as a check. But I'm going off line now! Glad you've got it sorted.